# Database Relationships - One-to-One that also has One-to-Many

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Let's say you have one cook that has one restaurant, and vice versa. So with a `one-to-one` relationship, you would have the primary key `id` in the cooks table and `cook_id` as the primary and foreign key in the restaurants table.

So how would you represent a relationship of `one-to-many` between the restaurant and its customers? Since the restaurant does not have its own ID, would the customers table have its own `id` and then contain foreign keys of `cook_id`?

---

Edit: I've thought of a better and more realistic example. Let's say you have a work order that only ever has one quote. You'll have the work order's `id` in the `quotes` table, since it's 1-to-1. Being a quote, it's bound to change, and that same particular quote gets revised. If you wanted to record the revisions made to a quote (or some sort of history log), you'd want something like a `quote_revisions` table. In this case, a work order only ever has one quote, and a quote can have many quote revisions. With what IDs do you link the `quotes` and `quotes_revisions` table?

Comment: 1:1 is rare.  Do you have exactly one cook per restaurant, and they never change?

Comment: That's correct. My question was more of a general design question I've wondered about, so I've provided a better example in my edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Work_order example:

- Work_order would have a PK of, say, `wo_id`, and it might be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- Quotes would have a PK with the same `wo_id`, but not `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- Quote_revisions would have an `INDEX(wo_id)`, but some other column(s) for the PK.

Work_order and Quotes are "1:1", as provided by `wo_id`.

Quotes and Quote_revisions are "1:N"; `wo_id` in both tables provides that relationship.

It is rarely useful to have 1:1, but your example might be a good use case.  (One table is relatively large and static, the other is relatively small and frequently changed.)

Comment: That sounds along the line of what I thought too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a one-to-one relationship, the cook's id is the restaurant's id too.  You can relate customers to restaurants by associating customer keys with cook/restaurant keys in a table (customers or another table).  The one-to-many cardinality is enforced by placing a unique constraint on the customer's key so that they can't be associated with more than one restaurant/cook.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead have a `restaurant_id` field as the primary key in the restaurant table, along with `cook_id` as a foreign key.  Yes, this structure would support a one-to-many relationship just as well as a one-to-one relationship, but I believe each entity should nevertheless have its own ID.  If you like, you can put a unique constraint on the foreign key, to ensure that the relationship does remain one-to-one.  Or you could simply have a single restaurant table that includes fields with information about its head chef.